# Why do some files generated by emacs have a tilde after their name?

Tags: files

I think they have smaller file sizes meaning they are zipped. Is this right?

Comment: FYI: I've filed an [enhancement request](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22625) to add an index entry for `~ filename suffix`, as this info is not so easy to find in the manual (it's in node [*Backup Names*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html)).

Comment: [Web search for "emacs tilde filename"](https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=emacs+tilde+filename&ei=UTF-8&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002).

Answer (score 8):

These are backup files created by Emacs. See [Backup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html#Backup) in the Emacs Manual.

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html#Backup-Names) also says this:

> When Emacs makes a backup file, its name is normally constructed by appending `~` to the file name being edited; thus, the backup file for `eval.c` would be `eval.c~`.

**Update:**

To answer the second (main) part of the question:

No, backup files created by Emacs are not compressed; the smaller size of `foo.txt~` compared to `foo.txt` means that `foo.txt` *was smaller* when `foo.txt~` was created.